# how to get all required driver for my pc

Tags: laptop, drivers

I brought the PC SAMSUNG NP-RV515L on Feb 2012 and in 2015 I lost my all important driver and still I am not able to fix it. So how would I know that which driver pack should I download to fix it?

Comment: Go Samsung's website, download device drivers, install device drivers.  "Driver packs" are only for people who want malware installed on their computer.

Answer (score 4):

Goto Samsung's website and search for all available drivers. Search below for your product:

[image]

which will find this page:

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP-RV515-A01US

The resulting page:

[image]

Make sure to click "View All"

Answer (score 1):

Go to the official website of your machine manufacturer  (Samsung in this case) and download the drivers from there; looking for the web I found your laptop drivers and you can download them  [from here (this link is for your laptop model)](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP-RV515-A01US): once on the webpage scroll down to the Downloads section and choose Drivers from the "View all" list, start downloading your drivers and as a last step install them.